# Renew list for every iteration

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, iteration, compare

I want to renew the "namelist" for each iteration and use "if" to compare "name" against "namelist". The first iteration will always replace the content of "namelist" because the "namelist" at the first iteration is empty. For iteration number x, I therefore want "name" to be compared with the list's content from the previous iteration, ie x - 1. I do not want to append "name" to "namelist" but replace the entire content so the comparison is always between "name" and the latest version of "namelist". The "#-line" in the code shows where I think the operator should be.

```
def loop():
    namelist = []
    a = 1
    while a < 5:
        name = input("enter your name")
        if name != namelist:
            # operator that replaces the contents of "name list" with "name"
        else:
            continue
        a += 1

loop()
```

Comment: Convoluted problem statement smells like a homework assignment... Can you include (based on your understanding of the problem) a simple example input and its expected output would be?

Comment: `namelist` starts empty. At iteration `x` you want to compare something against iteration `x-1`. That means either `namelist` grows in each iteration, or you're always overwritting `namelist[-1]` and it doesn't grow any more (past obtaining one element of course). This kind of functions like a variable itself, like `old_name`. Can you walk us through a simple example, i.e., what `name` is in each iteration and what the state of `namelist` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do, but when you do `if name != namelist` you are comparing a string with a list, if you want to compare `name` with something inside `namelist` you should do `if name not in namelist` (literally asking if its not in the list) or `if name != namelist[0]` (asking if its different from the first element of the list)

And I think the operation you want to do can be achieved by doing `namelist = [name]` (just redefining the list)